# Filter Dropdown List depending on other dropdown list angularjs ng-option

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-filter, angularjs-ng-options

I'm trying implement cascading drop down options using same JSON object to populate both the dropdown.

**CODE**

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.fruit1 = {};
  $scope.fruit2 = {};
  $scope.fruits = [{
      "id": "1",
      "value": "Apple"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "value": "Banana"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "value": "Cherry"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "value": "Fig"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "value": "Grapes"
    }
  ];
  $scope.fruit1.id = "1";
  $scope.fruit2.id = "2";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    1st list
    <select ng-model="fruit1.id" ng-options="x.id as x.value for x in fruits">
        </select>
    <br/> 2nd list
    <select ng-model="fruit2.id" ng-options="x.id as x.value for x in fruits">
        </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now when I select "Apple" from 1st dropdown that should get removed from 2nd dropdown. I cant figure out how to implement this.

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/keyurshah24/m371zeg7/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing with filter and ng-select found a very simple solution.

Just add Filter in ng-option.

```
<select ng-model="fruit1.id" ng-options="x.id as x.value for x in fruits | filter: {id: '!' + fruit2.id}">
</select>

<select ng-model="fruit2.id" ng-options="x.id as x.value for x in fruits | filter: {id: '!' + fruit1.id}">
</select>
```

It does all the magic.
This Answer makes my question so stupid.

[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/keyurshah24/m371zeg7/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-change` on the dropdown.
like:

```
<select ng-model="fruit1.id" ng-options="x.id as x.value for x in fruits" ng-change = "removeFromList(fruit1.id)">
    </select>
```

and in your controller :

```
$scope.removeFromList(val){
//remove val from list
}
```

Comment: i cant remove the item from list. as that same json is used again. i need to preserve the list. that's why i was looking a for solution with filter.

Comment: so why not creating a original list to save data, and two json list for each drop-down? so if you want to go back to old values just use original list....

Comment: my actual application has dynamic data like
<tr ng-repeat="application in application"> 
application 1 -> 1st list of approver , 2list of approver
application 2 -> 1st list of approver , 2list of approver
</tr>
 in context to my example list of approver is fruits

Comment: so if i select approver from list one it should not be there in list 2. if i update approver list for 1st application it would effect other application's approver list too.

Comment: didnt not understant you at all, can you create a jsfiddle ot snippet?

Comment: check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/keyurshah24/Lu105e6L/8/) i have same as my actual application.

Comment: i updated [fiddle]  (https://jsfiddle.net/keyurshah24/Lu105e6L/13/) but not working. what i'm missing?